# how does the licensing works with rational Tools

Tags: ibm-rational

hi there
   my company is planning to buy a licenses for Rational suite, (Clearcase, clearquest,Reqpro) does one license work to access all 3 tools or i have to buy a seperate license for each tool.
         my company has
                       150 developers
                       45  project lead or manager
                       30  tester
can anyone tell me how many licenses should i buy for this situation.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the licensing schema that you choose. The classic floating licenses are 1 for each user of each application. I am in the understanding that there's a suite licensing schema, but I am not sure.

There's a new Token based licensing schema available since version 7.1.2 that allows you to share licenses between products. Every products has a "cost" in tokens and you buy a certain amount of tokens. That way you can buy for example 100 tokens and have some people working in ClearQuest, RequisitePro, Requirements Composer, etc. all of them using the same kind of licenses.